# heartbleed and its impact on salesforce

Tags: security, ssl

As an IT professional, I am very concerned at the news that Heartbleed can exploit weaknesses in the OpenSSL architecture. Is there any risk to users logging onto Salesforce via browser or app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a salesforce [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3i6) around this that states the following:

> At salesforce.com, trust is our #1 value and we take the protection of
>   our customers' data very seriously. On April 7, the OpenSSL Project
>   released an update to address a vulnerability nicknamed “Heartbleed".
>   Salesforce is not running the vulnerable version of OpenSSL and there
>   is no impact to the Salesforce service.

I've not seen any other public facing statements.

Comment: Note that "is not running" refers to the time *after* the patch release. So this suggests that possibly one of the vulnerable versions *was* in use before; the claim is not that they were *never* affected (e.g. used a version without heartbeat at all or non-OpenSSL code). So a *principal* risk is involved with *having* logged in, not with logging in now.